# Open link in new tab using ui-sref in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to open link in new tab
but the problem here :-

[image]
all the Project code use ui-sref as decribed in the next picture

I need solution for this problem and i don't want to change in my project because it huge and has many dependance

Comment: why you share your code like image,may be it will be difficult to someone to help to you

Comment: a screenshot of your code is not a substitute for a [mcve].  You should consider making an [edit] to your question to provide more detail.

Comment: however, since it *appears* that you are using `<a>` tags, `target` shouldn't be affected by the fact that they are `ui-sref` instead of `href`.....

Comment: Post real code...not images of code